# Проблемы с билдом (на ПК в 3D) Unity

Tags: unity3d

ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ПОМОГИТЕ, В ПОНИДЕЛЬНИК НАДО ПРОЕКТ СДАВАТЬ, А ВРЕМЕНИ НА НОВУЮ ИГРУ НЕТУ(((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу создать билд игры, раньше такого не было, подскажите что нужно сделать? Скрин прилагаю.

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyOne;
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyTwo;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 moveDirection;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(keyOne))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(keyTwo))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity -= moveDirection;
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код "Player.cs" в студию!

Comment: По скрину вам никто не поможет, добавьте код

Comment: Добавил код в студию)

Comment: Ну там же первая ошибка ругается на UnityEditorInternal.

Comment: теперь иначе. щас дополню